# How to reload modules between RSpec tests with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, module

I have a module that can be configured like so:

```
module MyModule
   mattr_accessor :setting
   @@setting = :some_default_value
end

MyModule.setting = :custom_value
```

I'm testing different configuration options with RSpec, and found that the settings persist between different tests because they are class variables.

What's the best way to reload and re-initialize the module in between RSpec tests?

Comment: Show your test code.  How are you loading, how are you testing?

Comment: hi, I have the same problem.. Have you found any clean solution?

Comment: did you ever figure this out.. I have an attribute that I only want available on test machines, so I have tests that allow(Rails.env),to receive(:production?).. but once the first test runs, it messes all the others.  Alone they are fine.

Comment: Oh.. for this.. I'd use a mock..  allow(MyModule).to receive(:setting).and_return(:custome_value)  but your question may was contrived, so I might be missing the point.

Answer (score 5):

I came to this solution:

```
describe MyModule do

  before :each do
    # Removes the MyModule from object-space (the condition might not be needed):
    Object.send(:remove_const, :MyModule) if Module.const_defined?(:MyModule)

    # Reloads the module (require might also work):
    load 'path/to/my_module.rb'
  end

  it "should have X value" do
     MyModule.setting = :X

     expect(MyModule.setting).to eq :X
  end

end
```

Source: http://geminstallthat.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/reloading-classes-in-rspec/

Comment: FYI. Using `require` doesn't work. (Constant is not defined then)

Answer (score 0):

1: Did you try requiring the file in a `before :each` block?

```
require 'my_module'
```

2: I don't know if reloading a file is the right thing to do here. From what it seems all you want is some class's values to become default again, for that I'd just create a method that changes the module's values to whatever I wish.

```
describe MyModule do

  def module_to_default
    MyModule.setting = :some_default_value
  end

  before :each do
    module_to_default
  end
end
```

If you see a good use for defaulting this module values in your code it may even be a good idea to move the method into the module itself.

Comment: Solution 1 doesn't change anything - the file was already loaded and constants defined, it doesn't reload.

Solution 2 would work, but then it needs this to_default method which would only be used in tests. I'd like to stay away from that.